# laravel show unit test is not asserting

Tags: php, laravel, testing

i have a laravel application that i want to write tests for now when i run show test its not working and i am writing this test for my api btw :
so my test is like below :

```
public function testShow()
{
    $response = $this->json('GET', '/api/roomfacility/{roomfacility}', []);

    $response->assertStatus(200);

}
```

but i get this error :

```
    20) Tests\Feature\RoomCapacityHistoryTest::testShow
Expected status code 200 but received 404.
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

i want to know what is the error here because when i try it in browser it works and i want to know how to test my crud api ,
i want to test my index,show,create,update for my api i know there are some tutorials about the testing but they are not about the api .
**EDIT :**

just to mention the index method is working well with the same code :

```
    public function testIndex()
{
    $response = $this->json('GET', '/api/roomfacility', []);

    $response->assertStatus(200);

}
```

Comment: It cant find your URI. Try using a named route instead `$this->json('GET', route('route.name'))` and make sure it is correct. Also your route is expecting a parameter.

Comment: @Rudolph check my edited question

Comment: Try what I posed, `$this->json('GET', route('route.name', ['roomfacility' => 'whatever_value_it_needs_to_be']))`. Replace example values with the correct route name and expected value of roomfacility.

Comment: nope still the error exists its a bit wierd because it works with the index method

Comment: In this line:  
$response = $this->json('GET', '/api/roomfacility/{roomfacility}', []);
You dont set roomfacility - this is supposed to be an id of a roomfacility which it can open. You should do: 
$response = $this->json('GET', '/api/roomfacility/' . $roomfacility, []);